# PHP frontend Java REST backend on Red Hat OpenShift

Tags: java, php, rest, openshift

I want to create pet project with Java REST backend and PHP web-frontend(my friend will be on PHP side).

Is that possible to build application with such architecture on Red Hat OpenShift ?

Will it be scalable?

What about cost ?

Comment: Openshift supports Java and PHP so yes it's possible to have such an architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that possible to build application with such architecture on Red Hat OpenShift ?

Yes, OpenShift supports both Java and PHP.

> Will it be scalable?

Yes, if the PHP application and the Java application allows that. The OpenShift platform itself is scaleable.

> What about cost?

The price listing of OpenShift is outlined on their website: https://openshift.redhat.com/community/developers/pricing

Comment: It will be one application with Java and PHP 'gears' or it will be separate two applications ?

Comment: @Oleksandr.Bezhan: Whatever suits your needs. Can be even more than two gears. Separation suggests you have at least one gear per platform for scale-ability.